# conflicts of cblas APIs definition between OpenBLAS and Eigen 3.3.4

Tags: eigen, openblas

I am newbie to Eigen and hope to use OpenBLAS as a backend of Eigen 3.3.4 on Android/ARMv7. From the following site I tried a test to use them in one application (Compiling environment is ubuntu 16.04 + Android NDK r15c.),

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicUsingBlasLapack.html

gemm.cpp has code as follow,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

#include "cblas.h"

using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    double A[6] = {1.0, 2.0, 1.0,-3.0, 4.0,-1.0};
    double B[6] = {1.0, 2.0, 1.0,-3.0, 4.0,-1.0};
    double C[9] = {.5 , .5 , .5 , .5 , .5 , .5 , .5 , .5 , .5};
    cblas_dgemm(CblasColMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasTrans, 3, 3, 2, 1, A, 3, B, 3, 2, C, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

My Android.mk looks like this,

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
#build a test executable
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := gemm 
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /home/yangfan/workspace/study/eigen-3.3.4
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /home/yangfan/workspace/study/openBLAS
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/gemm.cpp
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DEIGEN_USE_BLAS

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fPIC -frtti -fexceptions -lz -O3
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lm -llog -lz
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/openblas-libs/libopenblas.a

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

When trying to compile the project, I encountered errors as follow(I picked one to paste here),

```
In file included from ././gemm.cpp:4:    
In file included from /home/yangfan/workspace/study/openBLAS/cblas.h:5:    
In file included from /home/yangfan/workspace/study/openBLAS/common.h:751:    
/home/yangfan/workspace/study/openBLAS/common_interface.h:105:9: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded    
void BLASFUNC(dcopy) (blasint *, double *, blasint *, double *, blasint *);

/home/yangfan/workspace/study/eigen-3.3.4/Eigen/src/Core/util/../../misc/blas.h:44:8: note: previous declaration is here
int    BLASFUNC(dcopy) (int *, double *, int *, double *, int *);
```

There are different return types for the same blas functions in openblas and eigen.

```
Q1. Why are there different return types for the same blas APIs in OpenBLAS and Eigen?

Q2. Is there something missing? Hope some guides to use OpenBLAS as a backend of Eigen.

Q3. Which version is higher, 3.3.4 or 3.3.90? ^-^
```

thanks so much for your help.

Comment: what about removing `#include "cblas.h"`?

Comment: Thanks @ggael for quick feedback.

Comment: Android toolchain complains - use of undeclared identifier CblasColMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasTrans. If removing cblas.h, where does the toolchain look for the cblas definitions? I mean I can't find cblas.h-like files in NDK dir.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have two interface styles - fortran blas hand cblas. Eigen only supports fortran blas calls and developers need not provide a header file. I should remove Eigen/Dense if only using cblas functions. 
But I still am puzzled at the issue. Why do Eigen and openblas define different return types for fortran-style functions?

in common_interface.h of OpenBLAS,

```
void BLASFUNC(dgemm)(char *, char *, blasint *, blasint *, blasint *, double *,
       double *, blasint *, double *, blasint *, double *, double *, blasint *);
```

in misc/blas.h of Eigen,

```
int BLASFUNC(dgemm)(const char *, const char *, const int *, const int *, const int *, const double *, 
       const double *, const int *, const double *, const int *, const double *, double *, const int *);
```